# How do I stop Visual Studio from automatically inserting asterisk during a block comment?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm tearing my hair out with this one. If I start a block comment `/*` in VS.NET 2005+ then carriage return, Visual Studio insists that I have another asterisk `*`. I know there's an option to turn this off but I just can't find it. Anyone know how to turn this feature off?

Comment: There is a uservoice suggestion to improve this http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2947213-don-t-create-asterisk-for-new-lines-within-block-c

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Update: this setting was changed in VS 2015 update 2. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36319097/4294399).**

[This post](http://forums.msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/csharpide/thread/a41e3652-efe2-4f81-ad3e-94994974fcb2/) addresses your question. The gist of it is:

```
Text Editor > C# > Advanced > Generate XML documentation comments for ///
```

Comment: That is highly irritating that I have to turn off XML comments in order to disable asterisk auto-insertion. They are two different things and shouldn't be bundled under the same setting.

Comment: It should be specifically called out that turning off **Generate XML documentation comments for ///** will also disable XML documentation comments for `///`.

Answer (score 18):

[Visual Studio 2015 Update 2](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx) has (finally) addressed this problem!

A new option as been added to `Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced` named `Insert * at the start of new lines when writing /* */ comments`.

Disabling this option prevents the editor from automatically prefixing block comments with asterisks.  It only took 7.5 years and 4 major releases :)

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
#if false

    whatever you want here
    and here

#endif
```

Comment: +1 for an alternative that doesn't involve turning off useful documentation features (Microsoft's fault, not the answerer's!)

Comment: this is a great solution for a temporary block comment, although I'd probably not use it for a permanent one