# Help with Visual Studio 2008 annoyances

Tags: visual-studio-2008, usability

I really like VS2008 but I was wondering if someone has workarounds for these annoyances:

- When I open a `/* ... */` comment block, VS insists on placing a '*' character on every new line. That's nice, but sometimes I don't want that at all. Is there a way to turn it off? The formatting section in the Options dialog for the C# editor doesn't seem to offer that as an adjustable option. I've also tried doing Shift+Enter and whatnot without success.
- VS2003 used to display the active filename and the project (if any) it belonged to in the main window title. E.g., "ProjectFoo - AssemblyInfo.cs - Microsoft Visual Studio" or something. That seems to be gone with no way to turn it on. I used to rely on the project part to navigate the solution explorer quickly, but now I find myself sitting there thinking which project the file I'm looking for belongs to. When you have 30 projects in a solution this tends to get old. And the auto sync thing is not an option here because I noticed it's slower in 2008 than it was in 2003 to begin with.
- VS2003 used to be lightning fast at compiling a project where a single file had changed and all its dependencies. It seems that VS2008 takes a hell of a lot longer to do the same thing. Why? I've looked at the options and all I can find is the "only compile enough to run when debugging" but that doesn't seem to make any difference in the speed of the builds. Is this a "feature" of MSBuild or something?
- Is there a way to turn off that glitzy selector that appears when I hit Ctrl+Tab and just have the thing switch to the next file?
- Why does VS2008 place tabs of newly-opened files at the *beginning* of the tab selector rather than at the end? I know this is an option in some editors and some people prefer it, but I want the last file I opened to be at the end of the tab selector. This doesn't seem to be an option, either.
- There is a really annoying lag I've noticed when I debug. As I step through code VS seems to be setting each opened file to read only and back. I mean I can see little blue lock icons appear and disappear in the tab selectors next to the file titles. I really need to just step through my code without having to see the whole window frame flash and flicker with every F10. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You really need to ask one question at a time.  I doubt that anybody's going to make the effort to respond to a laundry list of Visual Studio gripes.

Comment: Very well. I'll try that although it seems a bit like spamming maybe. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's too many questions for me to answer so I'll just take one and let others chime in
with the rest.

> When I open a `/* ... */` comment block, VS insists on placing a `*` character on every new line. That's nice, but sometimes I don't want that at all. Is there a way to turn it off?

The answer is found in [this duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307602/how-to-disable-the-automatic-asterisk-in-visual-studio-when-adding-a-multi-line-c):

> Tools > Options... > Text Editor > C# > Advanced > Uncheck "Generate XML Documentation comments for ///".
>
> (Of course, in addition to getting rid of the automatic * in block comments, this will disable the autoformatting when you type "///", as it says.)

Comment: Thank you, but that's no real solution. I still want the /// thing to work!

Comment: @prunet: I think there is no option for that. You will just have to choose which of the two options is least undesirable.

Comment: Thank you Mark for the answer regardless. I was looking at the macros that come with VS and I've noticed there's one in 'VSEditor' that looks like it might be doing this. I'll try to update my question if I find that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

Let me take another question:

> VS2003 used to be lightning fast at
>   compiling a project where a single
>   file had changed and all its
>   dependencies. It seems that VS2008
>   takes a hell of a lot longer to do the
>   same thing. Why? I've looked at the
>   options and all I can find is the
>   "only compile enough to run when
>   debugging" but that doesn't seem to
>   make any difference in the speed of
>   the builds. Is this a "feature" of
>   MSBuild or something?

This can be achieved by setting VS to only build the startup project and its dependencies as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tdasz7h%28VS.80%29.aspx):

> To build only the startup project and
>   its dependencies
>
> 1. On the Tools menu, choose Options.
> 2. In the Options dialog box, expand the Projects and Solutions
>      folder, and choose Build and Run.> 
>        The Build and Run, Projects and Solutions, Options Dialog Box opens.
> 3. Select the option to Only build startup projects and dependencies on
>      Run.
>
>    When this option is selected, only the current startup project and
>      its dependencies are built when you:
>
>    - choose Start (F5) from the Debug menu.
>
>      -or-
>    - choose Build Solution (CTRL+SHIFT+B) from the Build menu.
>
>    When this option is cleared, either of the preceding command builds
>      all projects, their dependencies, and
>      the solution files. By default, this
>      option is not selected.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately as far as I can see that has no effect - compile times are still way slower compared to VS2003.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is dirt old, but in VS2008 you need to open up tools -> Options -> Debugging and disable "Edit and Continue", if you want this behavior to stop.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps someone searching for solutions to VS2008 annoyances.  When stepping in native C++ code, I was getting a strange lag if my cursor was in a source file window.  I finally figured out how to get rid of it.

1) Go to "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Personalization" and select "Change mouse pointers"

2) Select "Pointers" tab

3) Disable/Uncheck "Enable pointer shadow"

Now I don't have to close my watch windows, auto window, etc..