# Enable the automatic asterisk to each new line comment and curly braces autoformatting

Tags: visual-studio-2015

First of all, yes I'm trying to **enable** the automatic asterisk to each new line comment. It worked on Visual Studio 2013 but it is not working in VS 2015 RTM.

I tried reversing the steps in here to no avail:
[How to disable the automatic asterisk in Visual Studio when adding a multi-line comment in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307602/how-to-disable-the-automatic-asterisk-in-visual-studio-when-adding-a-multi-line)

I reset all environment settings in the "Import and Export Settings Wizard" but didn't work.

In VS 2013 we also had the possibility to do the following:

```
public void Method(){**CURSOR IS HERE** }
```

When I pressed enter when my cursor is where I had indicated, I would get:

```
 public void Method()
    {
       //I would start typing immediately!
    }
```

Is it possible to return these behaviors back to VS?

Comment: Have you found a way to do this?  I'm trying to add it back too!

Comment: @red.october: Nope. I haven't. Been using Visual Studio 2013 for making comments. It's a pain... switching IDEs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found an answer to the multiline comments (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32151124/visual-studio-2015-not-automatically-adding-asterisk-for-multiline-comments)), but I have fixed the formatting.  It bothered me too!

- To enable the block text format go to

  ```
  Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Formatting -> Wrapping
  ```

  and make sure that

  ```
  Leave block on single line
  ```

  and

  ```
  Leave statements and member declarations on the same line
  ```

  are both checked.
- You can also change the indent of the code block when you do want it on the next line:

  ```
  Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Formatting -> Indentation

  Indent open and close braces
  ```

Comment: Thanks a billion pal! Never knew it wasn't implemented due to Roslyn.