# Error during editing of C# comment blocks: "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: Length"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

**This issue was fixed by updating VS2015 with Update 3. Thank you Hans Passant for pointing out this fix in the comments.**

When editing C# comment blocks, I get the error listed above. This seems to happen only when the cursor is directly to the left of a comment block and pressing Enter to push the block down.

This GIF will probably be the best explanation. The error happens when pressing enter.
[image]

This does not happen if the cursor is moved even one character to the left or right of /* and only at the left margin. If there are no other characters within the comment block, just /**/, then the error does not occur. Regular comments are not affected. To be clear, the error only happens when pressing Enter at this location, with '|' designating my cursor:

```
|/* comment block here */
```

Similar error messages found online seem to have other causes, as their solutions do not seem to work for me.

Comment: Remove the "//" from end of  the comment line above and try it... do you still get the error?

Comment: I'm assuming you do not have any extensions or add-ins installed, or you would have mentioned it, right?

Comment: It was [added very late](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32186234/17034), the Roslyn code in VS2015 is in general poorly tested.  Microsoft does agile lately, testing isn't agile enough.  Install Update 3, make sure it is not a bug in an addin, then you'll have to click the [New Issue button](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues).

Comment: Kixoka - yes, it still happens, even in a virtually empty C# file. Cody - I do have extensions installed, some of which probably came with Visual Studio Community or part of other packages (not sure what half of them are, honestly). This started happening in the middle of work, when I did not install or update anything for weeks. Hans - I have the latest Visual Studio updates (unless they are not automatically showing up) and my comment asterisks are showing up on a new line.

Comment: By the way `while (isSpriteFlickering == true)` is not idiomatic, just use `while (isSpriteFlickering)`