# Visual studio auto complete Doxygen tags for C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, doxygen

Is there a way to make visual studio automatically place the doxygen tags in a C++ source file ?

What I mean is for example this piece of code:

```
int foo(bool p);
```

If I type `///` on top of it, Visual Studio automatically generates the following lines:

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="p"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
int foo(bool p);
```

My question is: is it possible to do the same with doxygen (when I type `/**`)? To make VS generate the following:

```
   /**
    * @brief
    * @param p
    * @return
    */
    int foo(bool p)
```

My question is about writing the documentation tags (not generating the final doxygen).

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38260751/keyboard-shortcut-customizing-in-visual-studio-2013 gives some hints or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51180/how-do-i-stop-visual-studio-from-automatically-inserting-asterisk-during-a-block

Comment: For old version of VisualStudio, there are such plugins. [DoxyComment - C/C++ documentation tools](http://doxycomment.sourceforge.net/#introduction), [DoxyComment - files](https://sourceforge.net/projects/doxycomment/files/)

Comment: I am interested in the first case with the /// comments. How did you get Visual studio to autogenerate that? For me it only works in C# and not in C++ and I would love to use it with C++. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @RanjeethMahankali as far as I can remember I have not configured anything special to get the /// to work in C++. But the project I was working on had a C# part for UI and a native C++ part for processing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why this did not pop out on my search on Visual Studio Marketplace, but this does the job using `/*!` doxygen tag.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dragospop.CppDoxyComplete

Example:

```
/*!
 * 
 * 
 * \param b
 * \return 
 */
int foo(bool b)
```

Answer (score 15):

There is a setting in VS19 that does just that:

*Tools > Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > CodeStyle > General > Generated documentation comments style*

Set this to `Doxygen (/**)`

Comment: As of VS 16.1.3 I do not see this option. C/C++ does not have a "CodeStyle" section.

Comment: I'm running 16.6.3 at the moment. Guess they added it somewhere in between.

Comment: Just to confirm that I have it in VS2019 16.7.1

Comment: this is helpful but the output still uses /// to begin each line instead of the convention with asterisk.

Comment: The option exists in VS 2019 16.11.6. The styles "///" and "//!" are triggered by typing them and pressing enter, the styles "/**" and "/*!" are only triggered by pressing "Ctrl + /".

Comment: Now here is the catch: The trigger "Ctrl + /" works on English keyboard where "/" is a separate key. But for example on a German keyboard you would have to press "Ctrl + Shift + 7" which doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't know why this did not pop out on my search on Visual Studio Marketplace

For the VS2019 and VS2022 version there is [another extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=FinnGegenmantel.doxygenComments) based on the CppDoxyCompletion, but with a few more features.