# How to change visual studio's default output for the code commenting template generated from '///'

Tags: c++, visual-studio

First off, I've only found one similar question on stackoverflow which is from 10+ years ago, please don't reference that question if this gets marked redundant.

Next, I am not sure whether this feature is from VS or an extension I may have installed.

The question is, when I type in '///' I get the following default framework for adding header comments:

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sample_input"></param>
/// <param name="sample_output"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
```

How can I change this to the format I'm more used to using for Doxygen, similar to this?

```
/*
** @brief
** @param
** @return
*/
```

In addition to asking how to change this default behavior, I'd like to know if the 1st format shown above is Doxygen friendly.

Edit: some helpful answers and links, but I'd still like to generate the doxy comments to use the convention with asterisks instead of '///' to begin each line.

Comment: You can’t. C#’s documentation system only supports XML comments. The functionality is baked into the compiler. It’s not an IDE feature.

Comment: I see, that kinda sucks. lol. Maybe there's an extension for Doxy that could act as a work around...

Comment: You can't ask us to recommend or find a tool, software library or other off-site resource here, so if there is such an extension for Doxy you'll have to find it somewhere else.

Comment: Also Intellisense will know about `///` comments. So it is probably better to keep those.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual studio auto complete Doxygen tags for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53010626/visual-studio-auto-complete-doxygen-tags-for-c)

Answer (score 1):

If you use "Visual Studio 2019" started from "v16.6" follow those steps:

To switch to Doxygen, go to `Tools > Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > General`, and choose your preferred documentation style:

[image]

Once specified, you can generate the comment by typing the respective `///` or `/**` above a function, or by using the (Ctrl+/) shortcut.

[image]

The final result will be:

[image]

Quoted from: [Here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/doxygen-and-xml-doc-comment-support/)

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful but the output starts each line with '///' instead of the convention with asterisks, which I was hoping for. Still helpful, maybe ill settle with /// instead of /**

Comment: Write the asterisks three times instead of two `/***` or use the shortcut `ctr+/`.