# How do I stop Visual Studio 2019 from automatically inserting asterisk during a block comment in C++?

Tags: c++, formatting, visual-studio-2019, block-comments

When using Visual Studio 2019, when I hit enter within a block comment in a C++ file it adds a leading `*` . I've found a solution to this problem for C# at [How do I stop Visual Studio from automatically inserting asterisk during a block comment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51180/how-do-i-stop-visual-studio-from-automatically-inserting-asterisk-during-a-block) but the same option is not present for C++ and changing the C# option doesn't disable the feature for C++. This does not occur with Visual Studio 2017.

So when I have:

```
/*<cursor here>
*/
```

and I hit enter I want it to look like:

```
/*
<cursor here>
*/
```

but instead I get

```
/*
* <cursor here>
*/
```

Is there an option somewhere that disables this behavior or another way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- In VS2019, click menu `Tools\Options`
- In the search field up to the left, type `comment style`
- In the tree view that appears under the search field, you should see a few nodes, Select the bottom node in the `Text Editor`/`C/C++` tree (currently named `General`).
- To the right, you'll have a checkbox:
  `[x] Insert existing comment style at the start of new lines when writing comments`. Uncheck that.

Done.

Answer (score 0):

According to the link: https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/disable-new-extend-multiline-comments-in/1185751

It seems an issue, and the issue was fixed in 16.8. I suggest you could install the most recent release from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/. Or you could update your Visual studio.

Comment: I have Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.9.3. Ted's answer worked for me though. That solution is also present in the link you posted here.