# How to move **ALL** settings in VS and where is Visual Studio 2022 setting to prevent automatic insertion of a comment after a new line?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

This is annoying to the 10th power. I just migrated my solution to VS 2022, then exported and imported settings by going to Tools -> Import and Export settings. but it did not transfer everything.

So two part question:

1. How to move **ALL** settings from one installation of Visual Studio to another? I mean stuff like layout of debugging windows, open panes, etc. There must be a way to do it?
2. How to prevent it from inserting a comment after I click enter at the end of another comment? The best way is probably to show with a screenshot. How to prevent it from inserting what I showed in red:
3. [image: List item]

Comment: For your second question, there's a setting for C#, but I can't find one for C++. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51180/how-do-i-stop-visual-studio-from-automatically-inserting-asterisk-during-a-block

Comment: @ChrisMM oh wow. The same for C++. They stuffed it into the (https://i.imgur.com/aZ0gAcT.png)[XML setting] for C++ as well. Extremely frustrating. It seems like you need google search for the VS settings now.

Comment: Well, that's odd that it's not in the same place. Was looking under "Advanced" instead of the other options.

Answer (score 1):

Layout is not store with the other settings, unfortunately.

From [MS docs:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/customizing-window-layouts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022)

> These layouts automatically roam between Visual Studio editions, and also between Blend instances on separate machines, and from any Express edition to any other Express organization. However, layouts do not roam across Visual Studio, Blend, and Express.

Using procmon, I found that when creating a new layout, it accessed the following file:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_9b589298\ApplicationPrivateSettings.xml
```

You might be able to copy this file, but I do not know for sure (path might be slightly different)

---

For the sake of completeness, as you've already found, the comment option is stored in `Settings -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Code Style -> General`, and is the option "Insert existing comment style at the start of new lines when writing comments"

Comment: Do you know where they are stored? In what file or registry key? It's probably easier to just move that.

Comment: @c00000fd, edited to add where I think it's stored.